# Azure Pipelines "Require Template" check not working

Tags: azure, templates, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to get the "Require template" check working on a protected resource (Agent Pool, Service Connection, etc) in my Azure Pipelines.

I've got a shared template setup in a common repository (named "goldenimage-azure-pipelines-templates") that is defined as follows:

```yaml
# /templates/pipelines/master.yml
parameters:
- name: templates
  type: object
  default: []

stages:
- ${{ each template in parameters.templates }}:
  - ${{ each pair in template }}:
      ${{ if eq(pair.key, 'template') }}:
        ${{ template }}
```

Then I have a set of shared templates in the same repository that are referenced by the consuming azure-pipelines.yml file.

```yaml
# /templates/stages/main.yml
stages:
  - stage: mainBuild
    jobs:
      - template: /templates/jobs/set-version.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/build-image.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/cleanup-build.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/test-image.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/cleanup-test.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/update-configmap.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/destroy-template.yml
      - template: /templates/jobs/cleanup.yml
```

Now, in my consuming repository, I have the azure-pipelines.yml file defined as follows:

```yaml
# azure-pipelines.yml
name: $(GitVersion.NuGetVersionV2).$(Build.BuildId)

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
    exclude:
      - 'README.md'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: goldenimage-azure-pipelines-templates
      ref: feature/WI443-baseTest

variables:
  - template: /templates/vars/main.yml@templates
  - template: /azure-pipelines/vars.yml


extends:
  template: templates/pipelines/master.yml@templates
  parameters:
    templates:
      - template: /templates/stages/main.yml
```

And then in my protected resource (Agent Pool or Service Connection), I've defined the check as follows:

[image: Required YAML template]

But whenever the build runs, it ALWAYS reports that it has failed this check.

I've tried changing the syntax for the Ref to several different options such as:

- feature/WI443-baseTest
- refs/heads/feature/WI443-baseTest
- refs/tags/extend (made this tag just for this test)

I've also tried adding and removing the leading slash on the path to the template, and well as adding `@templates` on the end of it.

In addition, I have added and removed the template on both the Service Connection, and the Agent pool (in case it would work with one, but not the other).

No matter what I do, it reports that the run is not extending the template. However, I can see in the pipeline the jobs from the template, so it's obviously pulling it.

[image: Build Jobs]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi friend, is there any update for this issue? Still it can't work even with branch `baseTest`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68427396/azure-devops-required-template-check-not-working/68441882#68441882

Answer (score 0):

> No matter what I do, it reports that the run is not extending the
>   template. However, I can see in the pipeline the jobs from the
>   template, so it's obviously pulling it.

The direct cause of the issue is that your pipeline doesn't pass the `Require Template` check. I think the jobs are canceled because of that.

I found it could work well if all my resources were in branch whose format was `feature`. and same issue occurred if I used a branch like `feature/xxx`. So I think the second format branch is **not supported well** in `Require Template` check .

[image]

Check the pic above, according to my tests the check works well for `DevBranch`, but not `Feature/Test`.   I suggest you can post a feature request [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) to report this issue. Thanks for your help to make our product better :)

Comment: I created branch "baseTest" off my "feature/xxx" branch in my template repository, and then changed the check to use "baseTest" as the "Ref", and modified the consuming code to reference the "baseTest" branch as well, but it still does not work...

Comment: I checked it again with same steps like yours, but the `refs/heads/baseTest` in `require template` worked well on my side. Make sure you use `baseTest` in yaml: `ref: baseTest`. And then set `refs/heads/baseTest` in Ref, run the pipeline manually. Can it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: templates
      type: git
      name: goldenimage-azure-pipelines-templates
      ref: feature/WI443-baseTest
```

the **ref** in the pipeline should add the *ref/tags/** or at your case *ref/heads/feature/WI443-baseTest*

in the security approval is the same too, you may refer this article for more information [here](https://josh-ops.com/posts/extends-template/)

Answer (score 0):

I've got it now running and want to share here my knowledge, because the answers here weren't clear for me.

1. I added the "required template" settings on my pool "MyPool"

[image]

2. I extended the YAML-Pipeline

```yaml
pool: MyPool

resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: verifier
    type: git
    name: Project/Examples
    ref: feature/extends

extends:
  template: pipelines/advanced/extends/extends.yml@verifier
  parameters:
    stages:
    - stage: build_stage
      displayName:  Build Stage
      dependsOn: []
      jobs:
      - job: build_job
        displayName:  Build Job
        steps:
        - script: |
            echo  Build Stuff 
          displayName: Execute stuff
```

And now it's works like expected.

---

Here the content of the extends.yml

```yaml
parameters:
- name: stages
  type: stageList
  default: []

stages:
- ${{ parameters.stages }}
- stage: verifier_stage
  displayName: ️‍♂️ Verifier Stage
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: verifier_job
    displayName: ️‍♂️ Verifier Job
    steps:
    - script: |
        echo ️‍♂️ Verify Stuff ️‍♂️
      displayName: Execute stuff
```