# Azure DevOps "Required template check" not working

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I am extending  a template through repository resource in a yml pipeline (mainpipeline.yml), all working fine. project’s, repo folder structure details below.

My template is in  OrgA -> proj1 -> repoX -> branch -> templates/set1/template1.yml (only one stage in this template with one job and 3 tasks)

My main pipeline is in OrgA -> proj2 -> repoY ->branch -> pipelines/mainpipeline.yml

Created service connection sc1 in OrgA -> proj2 to invoke templates from OrgA -> proj1 -> repoX

But the issue is, added required template check to enforce “mainpipeline.yml” extends “template1.yml" with help of steps provided by [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#required-template). check not working, it’s not restricting main pipeline to invoke other then the one added in the check, there is no pass or fail info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by adding step "- checkout: repository" in template. Now, the the "Required template" check added to the service connection working fine, stopping main pipeline to invoke other then allowed templates.